# Retrieving data from different servers and databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two servers 10.10.7.10 and 10.10.2.10.  10.10.7.10 has the dev database with dbo as owner of a table named vendor.  On 10.10.2.10 I have the same table in a database name prod.  How do I retrieve data from both servers logging into  10.10.7.10 as a remote connection and using sql management studio to create and run my queries/

Comment: Yep I would use linked servers just very weary of ever linking Development to Production though!  What are you trying to do with the data?  Merge it? replace development or production with it?

Comment: I can only load files into the test environment.  Once I am done testing my loads there I want to execute them against production

Comment: So you are wanting to keep you dev environment up to date with the production?  If you simply wanting to test and NOT keep data in synch between them  I don't see a reason you should have them connected at all if that is the case, but I am sure I am missing something too...

Comment: and will I be able to update to prod from qc through the linked servers?

Comment: I have to use the dev environment to develop in.  I cant put any of my load or new files on the production server.  I can however update prod when on prod but I have files on dev that aren't on prod that I use for updates.

Comment: It is more than likely due to the locations of where your files reside.  If you can update on dev and the file path is c:\ that is because they reside on dev and the files themselves will need to be copied to production. Or if in a file share perhaps production doesn't have access?  You can connect to multiple servers from a single SSMS console from machines as long as those machines can communicate and your have permissions, but c: in a script will refer to a local drive on the server so files will have to be on that local server unless you setup and use a file share.

Comment: a linked server won't help with where files are located.  It would only allow you to communicate data via tSQL commands from one to the other but now share files between them

Answer (score 1):

Create a linked server and use four part name from your dev server to retrieve data from your prod server.

**Create a Linked Server**

Logon to your Dev server and add the Prod server as your linked server using the following command,

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server     = N'PRODSERVER'
                                 , @srvproduct = N'SQLSERVER'
                                 , @provider   = N'SQLOLEDB'
                                 , @datasrc    = N'10.10.2.10'
```

The above statement will create a linked server to your Prod server `10.10.2.10` now you can write t-sql statement from your Dev server using the four-part name. something like....

```
Select * from [PRODSERVER].DBname.dbo.TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a **Linked server** on your Dev server called Prod.

Then you can run a query like this

```
SELECT p.*, dev.* FROM PROD.dbName.dbo.VENDOR  as p 
inner join dbo.Vendor as Dev 
ON p.vendorId = dev.vendorId
```